# no modules in created own python package

Tags: python, setuptools

here's my py pyckage structure:
[image]

and `setup.py` content:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(name='lab_devices',
      packages=find_packages(include=['lab_devices']),
      install_requires=['pyserial'],
      version='0.1.0.0',
      description='Lib to easly manage lab devices.',
      author='Pawel Pietraszko',
      author_email='pawel.pietraszko@bmz-group.com',
      license='MIT',
      )
```

Every dir has `__init__.py` module (sometimes with imports) but after creating package `.whl` with command `python .\setup.py bdist_wheel` and installing my lib in project i see it - empty dir with no module, no package:
[image: Empty dir with just __init__.py and __pycache__]

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:
Replacing `find_packages(...)` with `find_packages('lab_devices,lab_devices.connection,lab_devices.cmds,lab_devices.devices'.split(','))` results with that main dir `lab_devices` containts subdirs with modules directly within them but without subsubdirs etc.

I remember about `--force-reinstall`.

Comment: Solved! Removing the kwarg `include` from `find_packages` helped. why is this kwarg called `include`? it sounds like "append also this packages", not like "only these packages"...